# SlimFramework: Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET

Tags: php, mvc, route, slim, slimframwork

Estou tendo dificuldade em resolver um erro que está dando no `slim framework`. Eu tenho uma página de contato que é acessada **/p/contato**, após acessar e clicar no botão de enviar, ele tenta enviar o `<form>` via POST para o action="" só que ele me retorna:

> **Method not allowed.**
>
> Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET

Creio eu que é por causa que ele está pensando que é GET e eu estou enviando o formulário via post.

A rota configuranda, que está chamando a view é :

```
   $this->get('/p/{pag_slug}', function($req, $res, $args) {
        $Paginas = (new \App\Models\Pagina);
        $paginas = $Paginas::orderBy('ordem', 'ASC')->get();

        $Informacao = (new \App\Models\Informacao);
        $info = $Informacao::first();

        if ($args['pag_slug'] == 'contato') {
            return $this->view->render($res, 'site/contato.twig', [
                'paginas' => $paginas,
                'info'    => $info,
            ]);
        }
        
        $pagina = $Paginas::where('slug', $args['pag_slug'])->first();
        if ($pagina) {
            return $this->view->render($res, 'site/pagina.twig', [
                'paginas' => $paginas,
                'pagina'  => $pagina,
                'info'    => $info,
            ]);
        }
        
    })->setName('site.pagina');
```

O que preciso é pegar os dados digitados no formulário via post para a url **/p/contato**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No framework Slim, ao definir a rota como:

```
$this->get('/p/{pag_slug}', function($req, $res, $args) {
   // ...
})->setName('site.pagina');
```

Você estará mapeando a URL `/p/{pag_slug}` apenas para o método `GET`, por isso do erro de não ser permitido o método `POST`. Para uma mesma rota aceitar múltiplos métodos, pode fazer:

```
$this->map(['get', 'post'], '/p/{pag_slug}', function($req, $res, $args) {
   // ...
})->setName('site.pagina');
```

Onde o primeiro parâmetro da função `map` define a lista de métodos suportados.

No corpo da função, pode obter o método da requisição atual através de:

```
$method = $req->getMethod();
```

Ou verificar diretamente através de:

```
if ($req->isPost()) { ... }
```

Acredito que os valores vindos do formulário estarão acessíveis em `$req->post({name})`.

Seu código deverá ficar parecido com:

```
$this->map(['get', 'post'], '/p/{pag_slug}', function($req, $res, $args) {
    $Paginas = (new \App\Models\Pagina);
    $paginas = $Paginas::orderBy('ordem', 'ASC')->get();

    $Informacao = (new \App\Models\Informacao);
    $info = $Informacao::first();

    if ($args['pag_slug'] == 'contato') {

        if ($req->isPost())
        {
            $name = $req->post("name");
            $email = $req->post("email");
            // Envia o e-mail...
        }

        return $this->view->render($res, 'site/contato.twig', [
            'paginas' => $paginas,
            'info'    => $info,
        ]);
    }

    $pagina = $Paginas::where('slug', $args['pag_slug'])->first();
    if ($pagina) {
        return $this->view->render($res, 'site/pagina.twig', [
            'paginas' => $paginas,
            'pagina'  => $pagina,
            'info'    => $info,
        ]);
    }

})->setName('site.pagina');
```

Comment: Amigo funcionou rsrs. Obrigado. Só não funcionouo `$req->post()` ... Se eu deixar ele, ele da erro 500. Troquei por `$form = $req->getParsedBody();`

Comment: Pois é, o método `post` existia para até a versão 2. Na versão 3 pode usar o `getParsedBody` ou `getParam`. Por exemplo: `$name = $req->getParam("name");`

Answer (score 0):

Caso nenhuma das soluções acima funcione, verifique se o botão de salvar encontrasse dentro da tag , se estiver dentro teste tirando de dentro da tag:

Exemplo 
Errado:

```
<form>
    <button class="btn btn-danger " id="salvar"> SALVAR </button>
 </form>
```

Correto:

```
 <form>

 </form>
<button class="btn btn-success " id="salvar"> SALVAR </button>
```

Dessa forma execute o POST via Ajax após o click no id salvar